# d3 - zoom to bounding box of SVG map element by clicking on a table row

Tags: d3.js, geojson

On this page:
http://public.johnnyotoole.fastmail.fm/county_map.html
I have a map based on some geoJson and a table based on a CSV file.  The Id of each SVG map element matches the rowIndex and Name of each county in the table.

Using the example from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541 if you click on a county in the map, it zooms in on that county.  This is done via the click() function. 
When a user clicks on a row in the data table I want to call the click() function to zoom in on the appropriate county, but I don't know how to select the appropriate item to pass into click(d).

In the map definition, click() in called as follows...

```
g.selectAll("path")
  .data(json.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("class", "feature")
  .on("click", click)
```

... so I guess this passes the data element that the user clicked on to the click() function.  When the table row is clicked, how do I select the corresponding element to pass to click()?

I tried variations of the following selector, but no joy:

```
d3.select("path.Feature[id='5']")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: If you want the DOM element being clicked on, just use `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code you've done most of the work.  As you indicate in your code what you need to do is link the csv to the json data in the tableRowClicked function.  However, before we do that we need to do some work.

We need to add a click event to the table cell, not the table row, as that's where we've appended the data (you could append some data the the table rows and then add the click event as well, but the code wasn't set up that way).  So I added the following to the cells variable:

```
 .on("click", function (d) { tableRowClicked(d); });
```

This will provide the county name to the tableRowClicked function.  All we need now is the json data.  To make the json data available I created a global jsonOutside and then passed the json data to this inside the d3.json call.  It was then just a matter of looping through jsonOutside until the counties match which was done inside the tableRowClicked function using:

```
jsonOutside.features.forEach(function (d) { // loop through json data to match td entry
    if (x.value === d.properties.name) {
        var county = d;
        click(d); // pass json element that matches td data to click 
    };
```

This passed the correct element from the json data to click, however, click needed to be slightly modified.  Everything was identified using the id or county, so the d3.select call was modified to:

```
d3.select("#"+d.properties.name).classed("active", active = d);
```

BTW I really like what you've done here and I've been meaning to do something similar.  I'd also like to post my solution on Bl.ocks, so let me know if that's OK (it also might make more sense with the full code).

One last thing I noticed was that you call referendum_results.csv twice.  This could be avoided by either incorporating the table stuff inside the first d3.csv call or by creating a global similar to what I did for the json data.  You could also avoid the csv file altogether by combining the results into the geojson data in GIS.  The json data could then be used to populate the table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent, that worked perfectly. Thanks for the taking the time to look at it. 

_Post on Bl.ocks?_ 
Absolutely, go for it.  I have a choropleth in my version, with two color ranges, depending if the result was above or below 50%. A next step would be to show additional information on the map once it zooms into an area.

_Avoid the csv file altogether by combining the results into the geojson data in GIS?_
I'd rather avoid that as I'd like to make it easy to switch in and out different datasets for different elections.

Comment: You can see the Bl.ock [here](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7557092) and the full code at [github](https://gist.github.com/phil-pedruco/7557092).  As for combining csv I hadn't noticed that you'd already done that, so in the gist you'll see I've moved the table code up into the first d3.csv call and removed the second d3.csv call altogether.  I also changed to a metcator projection from Albers, oh and I created a choropleth as well.

Comment: The Bl.ock is very useful, thanks.  I've moved `on("click", function (d) { tableRowClicked(d); })` up to the row level and changed `if (x.value === d.properties.name) {` to `if (x.County === d.properties.name) {` and now it works if I click anywhere in the table row.